# Multiple HTML 5 Canvases

Tags: css, html

I am new to HTML 5 and I recently created a page that has an issue.  I grouped my navi links together with a  tag and it works great.  The problem is that none of the other links on the page work at all.  This may be an obvious fix but I have been struggling for hours.  I can provide code but its 400 lines and I thought someone may have an idea.

Thanks for all your help

-Tom

Comment: This is part of troubleshooting, which you have to learn. Break it down into parts, and *think* about how you would post the parts. If you can't, *that's your problem* [sic], your markup is probably mixed up. If not, then do so. I answer most of my "questions" doing this *necessary* step before I ever click "Post Question" here on SO. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

For starters make sure your markup is valid. A good way to start is using the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). If that is valid do the same with the JavaScript using [JS Hint](http://www.jshint.com/) or [JS Lint](http://www.jslint.com/). And don't forget to check the developer console in Chrome or FireFox as it might show errors as well.